# Downloading Log Data from Mercurial Source Code Management System

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I need to download version control system data in a certain format for a data analytics. The data needs to be downloaded from mercurial source code management system. For example, following is the link to the files in the Mozilla-central repository

https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file

When I click on the revisions for any file in Mozilla-central, I get the data about all the commits made to the file through the following link

https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/log/tip/.cargo/config.in

My query is that how can I download all the commit data (timestamp, developer, commit message) for all the files in Mozilla-central repository for a specified data such as 1st January 2017 to 31st December 2017. Can I do it using an API or is it possible to download a log file in this (https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/log/tip/.cargo/config.in) which I can easily parse.

Thanks in advance and any help on this is appreciated. It is a general problem and not only specific to Mozilla Central. I want to do it for other repositories also.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command

```
hg clone https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central
```

in your terminal you will get all the commit history.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to create dataset of the commit log for a data analytics experiments and hence I do not want to just see the commit log on a terminal window but be able to save all the logs into a database or a text file. Preferable the revision history of all files in the Mozilla-central.

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute the query you desire, you need to obtain a local copy of the repository - you do not get comprehensive logs of a remote repository with all the requested information.

A local copy of the repository allows you to query the logs for any information the repo has available. Make use of revsets (`hg help revsets`) and templating the output (`hg help templates`) in order to retrieve the desired information and displaying them in the format you need.